# Spring boot Autowired Mongo Repository not working

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, autowired

I am trying to connect my Spring Boot application to mongo db following [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/)
tutorial. It is pretty simple.  I have a class ScanResults whose objects I am trying to save in a db when I receive a post request. 
I get the following error on autowired.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.gandharv.iiitd.ScanResultsRepository com.gandharv.iiitd.Application.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scanResultsRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Could not lookup mapping metadata for domain class java.lang.Object!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
at com.gandharv.iiitd.Application.main(Application.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.gandharv.iiitd.ScanResultsRepository com.gandharv.iiitd.Application.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scanResultsRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Could not lookup mapping metadata for domain class java.lang.Object!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
... 21 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scanResultsRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Could not lookup mapping metadata for domain class java.lang.Object!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Could not lookup mapping metadata for domain class java.lang.Object!
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:144)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:83)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:158)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
... 33 more
```

ScanResults.java

```
public class ScanResults {

@Id
private String id;

public ScanResults() {}

public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public ArrayList<WifiScans> getWifiscan() {
    return wifiscan;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public void setWifiscan(ArrayList<WifiScans> wifiscan) {
    this.wifiscan = wifiscan;
}

private String latitude;
private String longitude;
public ArrayList<WifiScans> wifiscan = new ArrayList<WifiScans>();




}
```

Repository Interface

```
package com.gandharv.iiitd; /**
* Created by GandharvK on 4/1/2015.
*/

import com.gandharv.iiitd.ScanResults;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

public interface ScanResultsRepository extends MongoRepository {

 ScanResults find(WifiScans obj);
}
```

Application.java

```
package com.gandharv.iiitd;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import com.gandharv.iiitd.ScanResultsRepository;
/**
 * Created by GandharvK on 3/27/2015.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    public ScanResultsRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.gandharvkapoor</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-wifi-scan</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Data MongoDB-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Spring Boot Maven Support -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay i solved it by commenting out find method in Repository. I guess its compulsory to implement all methods of interface.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to implement the Repository methods. Thats done behind the scenes. The problem is that you have not provided a template parameter to the repository:

```
public interface ScanResultsRepository extends MongoRepository<ScanResults, WifiScans> {
}
```

If WifiScans is a serializable object and is the Id of the ScanResults object, you don't even have to specify the find method. You will have `ScanResults findOne(WifiScans w)` and `List<ScanResults> findAll(WifiScans w)` methods available among many others (see MongoRepository and CrudRepository interfaces)